# How to dynamically control the audio volume based on current decibels

Tags: scripting, audio, pulseaudio, audio-volume

Since the Internet videos have different sound volume levels I am wondering is there a way to dynamically decrease the audio volume if it's above certain decibels to a normal value.

Could someone give me a hint with the script? Thanks!

I am using Ubuntu based Linux Mint 17.